# Unable to make pie chart from the dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testing Pie Chart</title>
         <script src="d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
         <style type="text/css">
         #chart {  
            margin-top: 100px;                                              
            position: absolute;  
            margin-right: 50px;
            margin-left: 50px;                                           
          }                                                                 
          .tooltip {                                                        
            background: #eee;                                               
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;                                    
            color: #900C3F;                                                    
            display: inline-block;                                                  
            font-size: 12px;                                                
            left: 600px;                                                    
            padding: 10px;                                                  
            position: absolute;                                             
            text-align: center;                                             
            top: 95px;                                                      
            width: 150px;                                                    
            z-index: 10;  
            opacity: 1;                                                 
        }                                                                 
        rect {
           stroke-width: 2;
        }
        path {
          stroke: #ffffff;
          stroke-width: 0.5;
      }
      div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 999;
      padding: 10px;
      background: #f4f4f4;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      pointer-events: none;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #000;
      line-height: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
      }

      .legend{
        margin-left: 300px;
      }
         </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <div id="toolTip" class="tooltip" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    var div = d3.select("#toolTip");

           var data = [ ["IP", "count"]
          ["192.168.12.1", "20"], 
          ["76.09.45.34", "40"], 
          ["34.91.23.76", "80"],
          ["192.168.19.32", "16"], 
          ["192.168.10.89", "50"], 
          ["192.178.34.07", "18"],
          ["192.168.12.98", "30"]];

    var width = 300,
      height = 300;
    var margin = {top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 20, left: 40},
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 10;
    var legendRectSize = 18,
        legendSpacing = 4;
          

        var color = d3.scale.category20b();

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius);
          
          var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius + 10);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) { return d.data.count; });

          var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 40)
            .innerRadius(radius - 40);
          
        var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var arcs = svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");
          
         var arcs2 = svg.selectAll(".arc2")
            .data(pie)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc2");

          
        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            var htmlMsg="";
              div.transition()    
                    .style("opacity",0.9);
                  var total = d3.sum(data.map(function(d) {                   
                      return d.count;                                           
                  })); 
            var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10;     
                div.html(
                 "IP :"+ d.data.IP +""+"<br/>"+
                 "Count : " +  d.data.count +"<br/>" + 
                 "Percent: " + percent + '%'+ htmlMsg)
                .style("left",  (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                  .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY) + "px");  

              svg.selectAll("path").sort(function (a, b) { 
                  if (a != d) return -1;               
                else return 1;                             
              });
          
            var endAngle = d.endAngle + 0.1;
            var startAngle = d.startAngle - 0.1;
            var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
                  .outerRadius(radius + 10).endAngle(endAngle).startAngle(startAngle);
                      d3.select(this)
                        .attr("stroke","white")
                        .transition()
                        .ease("bounce")
                        .duration(1000)
                        .attr("d", arcOver)             
                        .attr("stroke-width",6);
                  })

            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                  div.transition()        
                    .duration(500)      
                    .style("opacity", 0); 
                    d3.select(this).transition()            
                       .attr("d", arc)
                       .attr("stroke","none");
                })
              .transition()
              .ease("bounce")
              .duration(2000)
              .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

        function tweenPie(b) {
          b.innerRadius = 0;
          var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
          return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
        }

            var k=0;
        arcs2.append("text")
        .transition()
            .ease("elastic")
          .duration(2000)
          .delay(function (d, i) {
            return i * 250;
          })
              .attr("x","6")
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .text(function(d) { if(d.data.count >0){ k = k+1; return d.data.count;} })
              .attr("transform", function(d) { if (k >1){return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ") rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";} else{return "rotate(-360)";} })
              .attr("font-size", "10px");
          

        function type(d) {
          d.count = +d.count;
          return d;
        }
        function angle(d) {
              var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
              return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
        }

     var legend = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("width", radius+50)
        .attr("height", radius * 2)
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

     legend.append('rect')
        .attr('width', legendRectSize)
        .attr('height', legendRectSize)                                   
       .style('fill', color)
       .style('stroke', color);
      
      legend.append('text')
        .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
        .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
        .data(data)
        .text(function(d,i) { return d.IP; });
        
        
        </script>
      </body>
     </html>
```

I am trying to make a pie chart with the provided dataset and I am facing error. How to define the parameter d to fetch the data from the variable "data" and its subsequent values "IP" and "count"? I dont know what mistake I am doing in my codes. What should I change in my current codes so that I can get a pie chart with current data format? Please help me. I am stuck. The condition is I should not use any kind of .csv or .tsv file in this code for importing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't use pie charts, they are the servant of devil.

Answer (score 1):

- One issue is with your data array... you need to remove the first item in it [ Also, you are missing a ',' after the item. but the item is itself not required as its an array ].
- Second is with d.data.count inside the pie function... you need to refer it as d[1] as you need to plot the second item in data array in your chart.

Working code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testing Pie Chart</title>
         <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
         <style type="text/css">
         #chart {  
            margin-top: 100px;                                              
            position: absolute;  
            margin-right: 50px;
            margin-left: 50px;                                           
          }                                                                 
          .tooltip {                                                        
            background: #eee;                                               
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;                                    
            color: #900C3F;                                                    
            display: inline-block;                                                  
            font-size: 12px;                                                
            left: 600px;                                                    
            padding: 10px;                                                  
            position: absolute;                                             
            text-align: center;                                             
            top: 95px;                                                      
            width: 150px;                                                    
            z-index: 10;  
            opacity: 1;                                                 
        }                                                                 
        rect {
           stroke-width: 2;
        }
        path {
          stroke: #ffffff;
          stroke-width: 0.5;
      }
      div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 999;
      padding: 10px;
      background: #f4f4f4;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      pointer-events: none;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #000;
      line-height: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
      }

      .legend{
        margin-left: 300px;
      }
         </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <div id="toolTip" class="tooltip" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    var div = d3.select("#toolTip");

           var data = [ 
          ["192.168.12.1", "20"], 
          ["76.09.45.34", "40"], 
          ["34.91.23.76", "80"],
          ["192.168.19.32", "16"], 
          ["192.168.10.89", "50"], 
          ["192.178.34.07", "18"],
          ["192.168.12.98", "30"]];

    var width = 300,
      height = 300;
    var margin = {top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 20, left: 40},
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 10;
    var legendRectSize = 18,
        legendSpacing = 4;
          

        var color = d3.scale.category20b();

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius);
          
          var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius + 10);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) { return d[1]; });

          var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 40)
            .innerRadius(radius - 40);
          
        var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var arcs = svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");
          
         var arcs2 = svg.selectAll(".arc2")
            .data(pie)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc2");

          
        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            var htmlMsg="";
              div.transition()    
                    .style("opacity",0.9);
                  var total = d3.sum(data.map(function(d) {                   
                      return d.count;                                           
                  })); 
            var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10;     
                div.html(
                 "IP :"+ d.data.IP +""+"<br/>"+
                 "Count : " +  d.data.count +"<br/>" + 
                 "Percent: " + percent + '%'+ htmlMsg)
                .style("left",  (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                  .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY) + "px");  

              svg.selectAll("path").sort(function (a, b) { 
                  if (a != d) return -1;               
                else return 1;                             
              });
          
            var endAngle = d.endAngle + 0.1;
            var startAngle = d.startAngle - 0.1;
            var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
                  .outerRadius(radius + 10).endAngle(endAngle).startAngle(startAngle);
                      d3.select(this)
                        .attr("stroke","white")
                        .transition()
                        .ease("bounce")
                        .duration(1000)
                        .attr("d", arcOver)             
                        .attr("stroke-width",6);
                  })

            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                  div.transition()        
                    .duration(500)      
                    .style("opacity", 0); 
                    d3.select(this).transition()            
                       .attr("d", arc)
                       .attr("stroke","none");
                })
              .transition()
              .ease("bounce")
              .duration(2000)
              .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

        function tweenPie(b) {
          b.innerRadius = 0;
          var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
          return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
        }

            var k=0;
        arcs2.append("text")
        .transition()
            .ease("elastic")
          .duration(2000)
          .delay(function (d, i) {
            return i * 250;
          })
              .attr("x","6")
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .text(function(d) { if(d.data.count >0){ k = k+1; return d.data.count;} })
              .attr("transform", function(d) { if (k >1){return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ") rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";} else{return "rotate(-360)";} })
              .attr("font-size", "10px");
          

        function type(d) {
          d.count = +d.count;
          return d;
        }
        function angle(d) {
              var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
              return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
        }

     var legend = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("width", radius+50)
        .attr("height", radius * 2)
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

     legend.append('rect')
        .attr('width', legendRectSize)
        .attr('height', legendRectSize)                                   
       .style('fill', color)
       .style('stroke', color);
      
      legend.append('text')
        .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
        .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
        .data(data)
        .text(function(d,i) { return d.IP; });
        
        
        </script>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I found the solution somewhat like this: var data = [
      ["192.168.12.1", 20], 
      ["76.09.45.34", 40], 
      ["34.91.23.76", 80],
      ["192.168.19.32", 16], 
      ["192.168.10.89", 50], 
      ["192.178.34.07", 18],
      ["192.168.12.98", 30]];

var data = data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      IP: d[0],
      count: d[1]
    };
});

Comment: yea,, I assumed that you wouldnt be able to change your data structure, as you mentioned your constraints... so the provided solution was inline to the existing structure... It can definitely be done in a dozen other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your data input format is wrong.

Change from:

```
 var data = [ ["IP", "count"]
              ["192.168.12.1", "20"], 
              ["76.09.45.34", "40"], 
              ["34.91.23.76", "80"],
              ["192.168.19.32", "16"], 
              ["192.168.10.89", "50"], 
              ["192.178.34.07", "18"],
              ["192.168.12.98", "30"]];
```

to

```
var data = [ 
          {"IP":"192.168.12.1", "count":"20"}, 
          {"IP":"76.09.45.34", "count":"40"},
          {"IP":"34.91.23.76", "count":"80"},
          {"IP":"192.168.19.32", "count":"16"},
          {"IP":"192.168.10.89", "count":"50"},
          {"IP":"192.178.34.07", "count":"18"},
          {"IP":"192.168.12.98", "count":"30"}
          ];
```

Comment: Earlier my data was like the second one that you suggested

Comment: Yes the data is supposed to look like the later but if you are getting data as in quesion from source then you need to tweak and modify the data to make it in the format as mentioned earlier it was.

Comment: Thank you SiddP for your response. I have changed my data format and able to access it through mapping :                                              var data = [ ["192.168.12.1", 20], ["76.09.45.34", 40], ["34.91.23.76", 80], ["192.168.19.32", 16], ["192.168.10.89", 50], ["192.178.34.07", 18], ["192.168.12.98", 30]]; var data = data.map(function(d) { return { IP: d[0], count: d[1] }; });